# How to fix URL canonicalization with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, canonical-link

I wan't the server to always redirect my URL's to format as "http://www.domain.com", even if the user write just "domain.com".

I could find some examples of this on the web, but I already have some fixes in .htaccess file and I don't know, where to put what, so it does't clash with the previous code.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404

RewriteRule ^adminator/?$ adminator/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2&detail3=$3&detail4=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2&detail3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What should I put in, so it does the URL redirect to "www"?

And one last question, is it all I have to do, so search engines don't have problems with the URL's?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the contrary.

> you probably want www.example.com to forward to example.com -- shorter URLs
>   are sexier.
>   no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

Thanks to [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), I usually add :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you want to do that in your .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^adminator/?$ adminator/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2&detail3=$3&detail4=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2&detail3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1&detail2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?detail1=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Else, try the inverse `RewriteCond` and associate `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

Your  `[^/\\.]` pattern simplifies to `[^/.]` as the period does NOT need escaping.